# How do i find range of locations of a word in a sentence in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do i find range of locations of a specific word in a sentence in objective c?

Lets say i have the following NSString

```
NSString *stringOfHashTags = "mr#hello Mr.#hello"
```

I am using

```
NSString word=@"hello";
    NSRange termsRange = [stringOfHashTags rangeOfString:[word substringFromIndex:[word rangeOfString:@"#"].location]];
```

to find the location of a word that starts with # but if the word exists two or more times in the sentence it only returns the first location. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [enumerateSubstringsInRange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416774-enumeratesubstringsinrange) (searching and reading documentation is always the starting point).

Simple example:

```
NSString *aString = @"mr#hello Mr.#hello";
NSString *word = @"hello";
[aString enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [aString length])
                            options:NSStringEnumerationByWords | NSStringEnumerationLocalized
                         usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop){
    if ([substring rangeOfString:word options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
        /* do whatever */;
        NSLog(@"found at: %@ / %@", [NSValue valueWithRange:substringRange], [NSValue valueWithRange:enclosingRange]);
    }
}];
```

debug console output:

```
proj[64417:6900139] found at: NSRange: {3, 5} / NSRange: {3, 6}
proj[64417:6900139] found at: NSRange: {13, 5} / NSRange: {13, 5}
```

---

**Edit**

If you want to find all *words* that begin with `#` in a string such as:

```
"this #is a #test of #88 including embedded #tags such as Mr.#tags. #Is that #what you're looking #for?"
```

as opposed to finding multiple occurrences of a word (as in your question), you likely want to use Regular Expressions.

Another quick, simple example:

```
NSString *searchedString = @"this #is a #test of #88 including embedded #tags such as Mr.#tags. #Is that #what you're looking #for?";
NSRange searchedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [searchedString length]);

// searching for any Word that begins with #
NSString *pattern = @"\\#\\w+";
NSError  *error = nil;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: pattern options:0 error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Could not create regex!!!");
    return;
}

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:searchedString options:0 range: searchedRange];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSString *matchText = [searchedString substringWithRange:[match range]];
    NSLog(@"match: %@", matchText);
}
```

debug console output:

```
proj[66898:6935236] match: #is
proj[66898:6935236] match: #test
proj[66898:6935236] match: #88
proj[66898:6935236] match: #tags
proj[66898:6935236] match: #tags
proj[66898:6935236] match: #Is
proj[66898:6935236] match: #what
proj[66898:6935236] match: #for
```

---

**Edit 2**

Your second comment really should be a new post, as it's an entirely different question (about RegEx syntax).

But, to get you on your way...

```
NSString *searchedString = @"These #tags, with #various& #excluded! #chars. And #other@ formats #88 including #emojis or # even middle#tags";
NSRange searchedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [searchedString length]);

// searching for any Sub-String that
//  begins with #
//  ends with a character from an "end" set
//
// Notes:
//  \s means any white-space
//  \ needs to be escaped, e.g. \\ or \\s
//  you probably want to add more "end" chars

NSString *endChars = @"\\s\\?!@;:%^&*().,";
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\#[^%@]+", endChars];
NSError  *error = nil;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: pattern options:0 error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Could not create regex!!!");
    return;
}

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:searchedString options:0 range: searchedRange];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSString *matchText = [searchedString substringWithRange:[match range]];
    NSLog(@"match: %@", matchText);
}
```

debug console output:

```
proj[73128:7009059] match: #tags
proj[73128:7009059] match: #various
proj[73128:7009059] match: #excluded
proj[73128:7009059] match: #chars
proj[73128:7009059] match: #other
proj[73128:7009059] match: #88
proj[73128:7009059] match: #emojis
proj[73128:7009059] match: #
proj[73128:7009059] match: #tags
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to add all word that start with # even with number #88 with numbers and any language not only english...is this possible?

Comment: @stefanosn - see the **Edit** to my answer. (You've asked enough questions here to know that you should ask your *actual question* when you make your post.)

Comment: I am so sorry! Works great and excludes @!?:; after the # but i need to detect if there are emoticons, any emoticon after the # is this somehow possible?

Comment: @stefanosn - search for `regex find substrings between characters` ... but see **Edit 2** to get you started.